# PyInstaller packaged flask app failes to load Python Library, dlopen -> image not found

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I've packaged a [this simple flask app](https://github.com/SimplyAhmazing/pyinstaller-tut) using PyInstaller but my OSX executable fails to run and shows the following executable,

```
Error loading Python lib '/Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/Python': dlopen(/Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/Python, 10): image not found
```

My guess is that PyInstaller is not packaging Python with my app. Here's what I ran,

```
$ pyinstaller hello_flask.spec --onedir
83 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2
83 INFO: Python: 3.4.3
87 INFO: Platform: Darwin-13.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
89 INFO: UPX is not available.
90 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut',
 '/Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut']
90 INFO: checking Analysis
99 INFO: checking PYZ
104 INFO: checking PKG
105 INFO: Building because toc changed
105 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
144 INFO: Bootloader /opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/3.4.3/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Darwin-64bit/run_d
144 INFO: checking EXE
145 INFO: Building because toc changed
145 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
145 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/build/hello_flask/hello_flask
155 INFO: Fixing EXE for code signing /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/build/hello_flask/hello_flask
164 INFO: checking COLLECT
WARNING: The output directory "/Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/hello_flask" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/n)y
1591 INFO: Removing dir /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/hello_flask
1597 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
2203 INFO: checking BUNDLE
WARNING: The output directory "/Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/n)y
3947 INFO: Removing dir /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app
3948 INFO: Building BUNDLE out00-BUNDLE.toc
3972 INFO: moving BUNDLE data files to Resource directory
```

When I open the contents of the packaged app in OSX I get the following files,

```
myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/
  _struct.cpython-34m.so
  hello_flask
  zlib.cpython-34m.so
```

When I double click the above `hello_flask` executable I get the following output in my terminal,

```
/Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/hello_flask ; exit;                        
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/hello_flask
LOADER: homepath is /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/hello_flask
LOADER: Extracting binaries
LOADER: Executing self as child
LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/hello_flask
LOADER: homepath is /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS
LOADER: archivename is /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/hello_flask
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: Python library: /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Error loading Python lib '/Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/Python': dlopen(/Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/Python, 10): image not found
LOADER: Back to parent (RC: 255)
LOADER: Doing cleanup
LOADER: Freeing archive status for /Users/ahmed/Code/play/py-install-tut/dist/myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/hello_flask

[Process completed]
```

I've also tried running this on a co-workers mac OSX and I get the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding the image after packaging the app? Im not sure that the packaging adds the images( not 100% sure) but I have had similar issues in the past and have added the img after packaging

Comment: @glls I'm not sure what image this is that I'm missing. My code isn't using anything special...

Comment: myscript.app/Contents/MacOS/Python, 10): image not found  --- are you trying to load some image ?  maybe im missing something?

Comment: I'm not trying to load any special image or anything. The only dependency this project has is flask. I also tried to package an app that just printed 'hello world' and I get the same error..

Comment: I want to say PyInstaller isn't packaging python itself..

Comment: can you share an example of what you are trying to package that generates the same error?

Comment: the 'hello_flask.py' https://github.com/SimplyAhmazing/pyinstaller-tut

Answer (score 1):

I do realize it is an old post, but just came across the same problem, and found a possible solution - just in case anyone else finds it useful. Probably it is not ideal, I'm sure something must be missing somewhere, but anyway...

The pyinstaller creates a myscript directory and a myscript.app file in the dist directory. I managed to get the app running by manually copying everything from the dist/myscript into the myscript.app/Contents/MacOS

After that the myscript.app file successfully started the program for me, and also can be distributed without the myscript directory.

No idea why pyinstaller does not copy everything over automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As [Ireneusz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104663/ireneusz) mentioned in their post, you can copy the bundle from the 'hello_flask' folder and it will work, but to provided further information as to *how* to get PyInstaller to do the work for you, edit your BUNDLE spec class in the following manner:

```
a = Analysis(...
pyz = PYZ(a...
exe = EXE(pyz, a...
coll = COLLECT(exe, a...
app = BUNDLE(coll,...
```

If you point the BUNDLE class at the COLLECT object instead of the EXE, the build will bundle all of the parts as it does with the non-app bundle dist. As you can see, each class is nested into the next in some manner, so this will simply nest your build into your bundle.